# Limitations of Amazon RDS's Trial

Tags: amazon-rds

I'm not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question, but I'd like to give Amazon RDS's trial a go. Previously I've used Microsoft SQL Azure's trial and they cut me off as soon as I overshot the limit, preventing me from paying a single cent.

However, with Amazon RDS's trial, it seems that I will be charged as soon as I exceed their limits. I'd just like to know if there's anything in particular I should look out for, that I might miss out, and be charged because of that.

Of course, I'd prefer it if there is a way for me to prevent me from exceeding the free-of-charge limits.

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't set a hard limit. As far as I can tell the only limits you can hit are the time one or the IO limit: RDS won't magically grow your storage size or your instance size for you.

You can however setup a billing alert: amazon billing charges are available as a metric in cloud watch (amazon's monitoring system), so you can create alerts base on them (for example to send you an email). You can set this up from the [account activity page](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/index.html?ie=UTF8&action=activity-summary) or you can configure the alerts as you would with any other cloudwatch metric.

Comment: Good answer. I asked the Amazon service for help and that is exactly what they told me. They told me that I can set the alert at $0.00 so if I ever exceed the free limit I will be alerted by email.